# PyQtGraph Graphics Layout Widget issue

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to create a plot layout using PyQtGraph within a PyQt application.

I need a single row with two plots the first two columns wide and the second a single column wide.

Reading the docs I presumed something like this would work:

```
# Create the PyQtGraph Plot area
self.view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
self.w1 = self.view.addPlot(row=1, col=1, colspan=2, title = 'Data1')
self.w2 = self.view.addPlot(row=1, col=3, colspan=1, title = 'Data2')
```

But in this case I get two plot areas each taking 50% of the window width.

What am I doing wrong?

Best Regards,

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`colspan` allows you to let a cell in the grid layout span over multiple columns. I a way it merges multiple grid cells. In your example you end up with a grid of 1 row by 3 columns. The first two columns apparently each have a width of 25% of the total (or one has 0% and the other 50%), and the third column takes the other 50%. In short: `colspan` does not allow you to control the width of the columns.

So, how to set the width of the columns or their contents? That was surprisingly hard to find. There seem to be no PyQtGraph methods that handle this directly, you must use the underlying Qt classes.

A `pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget` has as its central item a `pg.GraphicsLayout`. This in turn has a `layout` member that contains a Qt `QGraphicsGridLayout`. This allows you to manipulate the column widths with: `setColumnFixedWidth`, `setColumnMaximimumWidth`, `setColumnStretchFactor`, etc. Something like this may be what you need:

```
self.view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
self.w1 = self.view.addPlot(row=0, col=0, title = 'Data1')
self.w2 = self.view.addPlot(row=0, col=1, title = 'Data2')

qGraphicsGridLayout = self.view.ci.layout
qGraphicsGridLayout.setColumnStretchFactor(0, 2)
qGraphicsGridLayout.setColumnStretchFactor(1, 1)
```

Take a look in [the documentation of QGraphicsGridLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsgridlayout.html) and experiment a bit.